# how to create new field with new datatype in Solr

Tags: solr

How to create a new field with new datatype in Solr and which files I need to modify to implement it with respect to version Solr 4.7.2.

And I wan't to use this field as unique key constraints in my Solr

Comment: check the managed-schema.xml ...

Comment: Hi Abhijit I have modified schema.xml new data type and overriding the  existing field. But I am getting following error        {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Error initializing QueryElevationComponent.,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Error initializing QueryElevationComponent.
 at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:827)

Comment: Can you share the schema.xml...?

Comment: You'll have to fix the error that stops Solr from initializing your core - from the exception it sounds like you have an issue with the QueryElevationComponent. If you're not using it - remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new field to `managed-schema.xml` or `schema.xml` file.

This file will be in one of the `configsets` you are using.

Or can be found in the core you have created.